# Apollo Server with prisma 2

Tags: graphql, apollo-server, prisma, prisma-graphql, prisma2

I am trying to create Apollo server + Lambda + primsa2

```
const server = new ApolloServer({
    typeDefs
    resolvers,
    playground: {
        endpoint: "/dev/graphql"
    }
})
```

But what I have from prisma2 schema is like

```
generator client {
  provider = "prisma-client-js"
  binaryTargets = ["native", "rhel-openssl-1.0.x"]
}

datasource db {
  provider = "mysql"
  url      = env("DATABASE_URL")
}

model menu {
  idmenu    Int         @default(autoincrement()) @id
  menu_name String      @default("")
  shop_menu shop_menu[]
}
```

DB is using mysql

My question is
How do I create basic typeDefs automatically from the system? Should I create typeDef manually?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to create the typedefs yourself or if you're using [Nexus](https://nexusjs.org) you can create the required models and that generate the typedefs automatically.